# How do I create an XML file with ASP.NET and have it prompt to download?

Tags: asp.net

I'm currently trying to write data (client machine) into a xml file where the user can save. However, I want the users to be able to decide on where they want to save this written xml file. Is there any controls or codes that I can use to allow the users to save the file?.

Update:

is that right way to do?

```
**HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(xw.ToStroing()); <<< ??????**
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

update:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName));        

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings))

                {
                    xw.WriteStartDocument();

                    xw.WriteStartElement("Name");
                    xw.WriteStartElement("Application");
                     ................
                    ......................
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(xw.ToStroing());
                      HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the [link](http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article76.aspx) helps me :)

Answer (score 1):

When you begin a file download, the client's browser will handle the file saving location.

If you want to force the file to download instead of open, add this HTTP header to your response:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myFile.xml"
```

Comment: i am using and i have update my question, please see and still dont work

Comment: try this instead:
`using(XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(Response.OutputStream))`
and then don't do the `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write()`

Comment: also, not sure if you noticed `xw.ToStroing()` is misspelled

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `MemoryStream` being used?  You should pass the `StringWriter` to the `XmlTextWriter` constructor then `Response.Write()` the contents of the `StringWriter`

Answer (score 0):

Add this after the Response.AddHeader line:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

This will force download of files, regardless the file type.